# Update table column with another column values of the same table using updateAll()

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table that contains these two real fields `current` and `origin`.

`current` value is updated regularly. I want to write a script of reset: for each row I want to put the `origin` value in the `current` value.

In **MySQL** it's possible with this query:

```
update MyTable set current = origin
```

I tried to write this in Yii2 with the query builder:

```
return $this->updateAll(['current' => 'origin']);
```

But this doesn't work because `origin` is interpreted as string and all rows updated with the value `0`.

So how I can update field value by the value of another field using `updateAll()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap `origin` in [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) like so:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

return $this->updateAll(['current' => new Expression('origin')]);
```

and result will be as expected.